# Can 2 $_POST conflict with eachother?

Tags: php, forms, post

So I am trying to use the intel I got on the first $_POST on the second $_POST but when the second occurs the intel from the first is lost, what can I do to overcome this?

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['entrar'])) {
        $nr_processo   = $_POST['nr_processo'];
        echo "$nr_processo";

        $aluno = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nr_processo = '$nr_processo'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($aluno) or die ("Este numero de processo não está registado " . mysql_error()) ;
        $aluno_nome       = $row['nome'];
        $aluno_ano        = $row['ano'];
        $aluno_turma      = $row['turma'];
        $aluno_ciclo      = $row['ciclo'];
        echo $aluno_nome, $aluno_ano, $aluno_turma, $aluno_ciclo;
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
    <label> A que se deve a tua visita ah biblitoeca?</label><br>
    <label> Estudo/pesquisa</label>
    <input name="estudo"  value="1" type="checkbox"> 
    <br>
    <label> Leitura Periódica</label>
    <input name="leitura" value="1"  type="checkbox"> 
    <br>
    <label>Internet</label>
    <input name="net" value="1" type="checkbox"> 
    <br>
    <label> Audiovisuais</label>
    <input name="audiovisuais"  value="1" type="checkbox"> <br>
    <input name="enviar" value="Enviar" type="submit"> 
</form>

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        $estudo   = $_POST['estudo'];
        $leitura   = $_POST['leitura'];
        $internet   = $_POST['net'];
        $audiovisuais   = $_POST['audiovisuais'];
        echo $aluno_nome;
        $data = date('Y-m-d ');
        $hora = date('H:i:s');
        echo $data, $hora;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO entradas VALUES('', '$nr_processo', '$aluno_ano', '$aluno_turma', '$estudo', '$leitura', '$internet', '$audiovisuais', '$data', '$hora' )") ;
 ?> 
 <!--  <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://localhost/registosbib/agradecimento.php"> -->
 <?php 
     }
 ?>
```

Comment: How could there be 2 `$_POST`s?

Comment: The first one is running a form from another page, because I needed to share the $nr_processo on this page. On the other page I have a simple form so ppl can fill their process number, This was the way i found to take that and put it in this page

Comment: It doesnot matter from which page. `$_POST` is global.

Comment: Well, one solution would be to store the first $_POST in $_SESSION so that the values aren't lost. - _also_ mysql is deprecated, you should use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: If you want to different post actions and keep the values of first $_POST values then store them in hidden fields.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Im using mysql because I'm doing a work for school and this is what they told me to use.

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array of variables sent using the HTTP_POST mehod. The idea of "2 $_POST" is a nonsense. If you mean that could be a problem to refer to 2 POST variables inside the same script, the answer is simply **no**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You post entrar and enviar in the same request or 2 different requests ?

Edit:
The 2 $_POST doesn't conflict
Fix:
Use $_SESSION instead

`session_start();

$_SESSION['row'] = $row;`

Then in the second $_POST use $_SESSION['row']['nome'] instead of $aluno_nome and other $aluno_* variables

Comment: 2 different, basically, i have a form in one page, where ppl enter a number, and i want to send that number to the other page, the way i found was to use post,

Comment: a $_POST variable only exists when you have posted back a form.  If there are 2 forms on a page, or you;ve come to a page from another post, as soon as you hit the submit button on the second form, the first $_POST will cease to exist, and the new one will take its place.

Comment: Edited my Answer and notice that session_start(); need to be in the top of the script